# Is it possible to refresh an html input onChange of a selectbox?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, onchange

I have a searchform with a select radius, I search on a postalcode using an online api. The api auto submits the input if typed in, but after it submitted and I change the radius I have to type in the postal code again, otherwise the new data isn't sent.

I like to know if it's possible to refresh the input for the postal code onchange of the select radius.

My searchform:

```
<form name="input" method="post" action="searchresults" class="pro6pp_range">
<input type="search" onchange="validate()" placeholder="Zoeken..." name="search" size="85">
<input type="search" name="searchpc" required="required" class="postcode" value='<?= $postcode ?>' placeholder="Postcode (1234)" maxlength="4">
    <select id="selection" class="range" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">
        <option value="5">5 km</option>
        <option value="10">10 km</option>
        <option value="15">15 km</option>
        <option value="20">20 km</option>
        <option value="50">50 km</option>
      </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Zoeken">
    <br/>
    <span class="message"></span>       

    <span class="output"></span>
    <br/>
</form>
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
    function updateInput(searchpc){
        document.getElementByName("searchpc").value = <?php echo $postcode ?>;
    }
```

Also note the onChange function on my selectbox.

Comment: Can you show the code that use the API? Does that API use javascript to submit your form? Does the page refresh?

Comment: I think it should be document.getElementsByName and dont you think it should have index ?

Answer (score 1):

may be it will work

```
function updateInput(searchpc){
    document.getElementByName("searchpc").value = searchpc;
}
```

searchpc is your "this.value" of select tag.

please let me know if it is working or not.

***UPDATE***

you type 9101 and then if you select 10km then you can post the form like

```
function updateInput(searchpc)
{ 
    document.input.submit();
}
```

so we will get both 9101 and 10km in searchresults page.

**NEW UPDATE**

I think your small box input form should be like following.

```
<form name="small_input" action="searchresults" method="post">  
<input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" size="25" name="postcode"/>
<select name="radius" class="range" onchange="updateInput(this.value)">
    <option selected="" disabled="">Afstand</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
</select> 
<br><br>
<hr>
<br>
    <p style="float: right"><input type="submit" value="Opslaan"></p>
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="submitted">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="afstand">   
</form>
```

please let me know what's the status.

Comment: I think you should use `document.getElementsByName("searchpc")[0].value = searchpc;`. Because `getElementsByName` will return an `array`.

Comment: sorry i wanted to do document.getElementById("searchpc").value = searchpc; sorry my mistake...

Comment: could you help me with the code I used from Rohan's answer? he's not active.

Comment: please check the update that i have given.Is that you want?Please let me know.

Comment: You can try yourself here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/ type in 9101 you will see an small ouput. when you now select 10km you get 10 results on searchresults page.

Comment: in input type search i have given "Test" and in searchpc field i have given 9101 and then i have selected 10 km and it sends me searchresults page.What wrong in here?

Comment: are you getting search value , searchpc field value and distance value in post?

Comment: When I select one and it submits. I still get '9101' with 5km radius. Don't know why.

Comment: I'm setting the wrong value because of this.value I need the value of the searchpc input. so the postcode.

Comment: please check the update and lemme know if you face any problem?

Comment: That's not going to work at all. sorry, but the form isn't submitting + I've set a session on the input, but that's not the problem. When I have `(this.value)` on the select, it's inputting the select value into the searchpc field. that's not what I want. I just want to refresh the value in the input.

Comment: first remove this line document.getElementById("searchpc").value = searchpc; and then tell me what's the problem.

Comment: I  can't use your code, but when I delete that in my current code obviously nothing is changing.

Answer (score 0):

As I know `getElementsByName` will return an `array`.

So try to use `id` in place of `name`

```
<input type="search" name="searchpc" id="searchpc" .... />
```

And your function will be like,

```
function updateInput(searchpc){
    document.getElementById("searchpc").value = searchpc;
    // I think it should be selected value from select box notphp value
}
```

Comment: Allright it's refreshing, but I get the value from the radius now into the input. So when I choose 10km the input is updated with 10.

Comment: I type `9101` in into my input. and when I select for example 10km the value is changed to 10, but I just want to refresh the value of the input so `9101`